# Когда у существительных мужского рода множественного числа окончание -а, -я, а когда -и, -ы

Tags: окончания

Директора или директоры, учителя или учители и т. п. Есть ли правило? Правда ли, что окончание -а, -я разговорное, а -и, -ы литературное? И если это так, можно ли говорить с окончанием -ы, -и ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Директора или директоры, учителя или учители

Директор**а**.
Учител**я** (преподаватели) и уч**и**тели (главы учений).

> > Есть ли точное правило?

Нет, есть рекомендации словарей. А словари, в свою очередь, следуют тенденциям в языке.

> > Правда ли, что окончание -а,я разговорное, а -и -ы литературное

Для некоторых типов существительных м.р. есть тенденция переноса ударения на окончание. И поначалу да, формы с ударением на окончания относят к разговорным. Постепенно они завоевывают права гражданства и вытесняют старые формы.

Comment: Ни о чем. Про "смотри в словарь" уже три человека написали, а человека интересует закономерность, а не частный случай. Единственная небанальная формулировка про "права гражданства", но она голословна - и скорее всего не верна. *"Опроса не проводили"*, конечно же?

Comment: Браво, браво. Зело борзо. Я ж заранее знал, что ваша мстя будет страшной. Обидчивый ребеночек форева. )) А можно сразу три минуса поставить? Жалко, что нельзя, верно?

Comment: Слушайте, рассказывайте уже, что Вы что-то там "знали", в другом месте. На меня ваше "те тронь меня - вонять не буду" не действует.  Вы добились только одного, что теперь я каждую вашу глупость буду фиксировать. Даже ту, мимо которой раньше проходил. А Вам мне сказать-то по сути и нечего.

Comment: Мой обидчивый мальчик, выпейте водички. Если я буду указывать каждую вашу глупость, то и жить некогда. Проще отмечать дельное – оно у вас встречается довольно редко.

Comment: Я ж говорю, сказать Вам нечего. Но вообще-то я Вас и не читаю. Так что если ко мне есть какие-то претензии, рекомендую поступить так же. )))

Answer (score 2):

Форма на -ы (-и) свойственна книжной, преимущественно письменной речи, а форма на -а (-я) - устно-разговорной, профессиональной. Поэтому наблюдается параллельное употребление форм на *-а (-я)* с формами на *-ы (-и)*, но со стилистической дифференциацией: *корректоры* (книжная форма), *корректора* (разговорная форма). Но, как отмечает Д. Э. Розенталь, в современном русском языке продуктивно образование форм на *-а (-я)* типа *инспектора*, *слесаря*, *директора* и т. д.  В случае затруднения при выборе формы нужно обратиться к справочникам или словарям.

Comment: Ох, ну уж если такая пьянка пошла и нормально говорить "корректорА", по-Вашему, может будем говорить и "лифтерА", "режиссерА"?))) Или слова с Ё — исключения?)

Comment: Разговорная форма "корректорА" отражена в "Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке" Д. Э. Розенталя (параграф 153, с. 212).

Comment: Хм, не очень это радует, но буду знать, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

1) Сущ. м. р.  с твердой основой в И. п. могут иметь **основное** окончание Ы/И и **вариантное** окончание А/Я.

2) **Вариантное окончание А/Я имеет значительное количество существительных мужского рода:** А) многие слова с односложной основой: лес – леса, снег –  снега; Б) некоторые слова с неодносложной основой (в этом случае ударение обычно падает на второй слог от конца основы):  берег – берега, парус – паруса.  Если неодносложные слова имеют другой тип ударения, то окончание А/Я для них  является ненормативным, например: инженер – инженеры (грубо неправильно – инженерА).

3) Дом – дома, город – города — в этих примерах окончание А в И. п. является вариантным, но его выбор не вызывает вопросов, так как вариантное окончание являются единственным. **Проблемы возникают в том случае, когда одно и то же существительное может иметь два вида окончаний – основное и вариантное**, например: годы и года, грозди и гроздья, договоры и договора. Тогда при выборе окончания возможны следующие случаи: А) допускаются оба варианта как равноправные; Б) варианты различаются по стилям или по смыслу; В) один из вариантов считается ненормативным, хотя и встречается в речи.

4) **Различение по стилю**: штормы (нейтр.) и шторма (разг.). **Различение по смыслу**: лагери (политические)  и лагеря (для отдыха), учители (духовные) и учителя (в школе), образа (церк.) и образы (в литературе и искусстве), хлебы (печеные) и хлеба (злаки), счёты (инструмент) и  счета (денежные), роды (грамматические) и рода (войск).

5)  При выборе окончаний А/Я и Ы/И можно использовать **эмпирическое правило**:

Если в устной речи встречаются два варианта окончаний, то желательно запомнить те слова, для которых окончания А/Я и Ы/И по орфоэпическим нормам определяются как  **единственные** (второй вариант считается ненормированным, хотя встречается в устной речи): пОрты, тОрты, возрасты – **только основное окончание Ы**, сортА, цехА, теремА, отпускА, якорЯ – **только вариантное окончание А/Я**.

В остальных случаях вариантное окончание А/Я является или **разговорным** (ветры и ветра, почерки и почерка, рапорты и рапорта, полюсы и полюса), или **ненормированным** (тортА, возрастА – не допускается).

6) Только вариантное окончание имеют существительные профессорА, директорА, докторА, шулерА. Форма профЕссоры соответствует старой норме, а также встречается у поэтов. Согласно словарям только форма директорА является нормативной, хотя  ещё в начале 20 века говорили дирЕкторы; однако сейчас  форма дирЕкторы, кажется, начинает вновь активно использоваться.

Comment: Ой, да тут вопрос-то гораздо **у**же...  Про существительные на -ор/-ер.

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, уже, Вы правы, но   тема  вариантных окончаний, кажется, не изучается в средней школе, поэтому у наших пользователей очень смутное обо всём этом  представление. В то же время,  простое определение статуса окончания помогает  хотя бы как-то систематизировать информацию и ориентироваться в ней.

Comment: Я не против, что та тема неисчерпаемая, но здесь-то явно не обо всех этих заморочках, дайте человеку хоть с частностями разобраться более или мене адекватно.

Comment: Sibylla, а что значит "с твёрдой основой"? И ещё, правильно говорить и "доктор**а** наук", то есть не только про врачей? Мне кажется, что да, но хочется убедиться.

Comment: 1) Да, вы правы, твердая основа относится не к И.п., а к Р.п. Основные окончания для сущ. м.р. 2-го  скл.: столы, жители – окончание Ы/И в И.п., столов, жителей, листьев – окончание ОВ (твердый вариант) и окончания ЕЙ и ЕВ (мягкий вариант)  в Р.п.   2)  Из словаря: ДОКТОР, -а; мн. доктора; м. [от лат. doctor - учитель, преподаватель] 1. Разг. =Врач.  2. Высшая учёная степень; лицо, которому присуждена эта степень. Д. наук.

Comment: Спасибо! Нашёл на  Грамоте: доктор, -а; мн. -а, -ов ***(во всех случаях).***

Comment: *Нашёл на Грамоте: доктор,*  - для Вас это новость? Да, "доктор**а**" давно уже стало императивной нормой. Как и директор**а**.- и еще некоторые. Но пока это примеры единичные, большинство подобных слов (на -ор/-ер с предпоследним ударнм слогом) все-таки как минимум допускает и классическое  способ образования множественного - на "-ы".

Answer (score 0):

Стася правильно ответила, единого правила нет. 
Но тут вот какое дело. Нормативными формы на -а/-я могут являться почти исключительно только для существительных с суффиксами -ор/-ер и ударением  *только* на предпоследнем слоге.

Поэтому, например, форма "шофера" никогда не будет правильной, поскольку образована может быть только от неправильного "шОфер". Точно так же сомнительна нормативность "слесаря". Как верно было сказано, все эти формы максимум - разговорные.

Но для существительных, этому свойству удовлетворяющих, надо смотреть словарь.

Comment: Мне кажется, надо ещё обратить внимание на сущ. с основой на ЛЬ, там тоже возможны разные варианты: вензель – вензеля, дупель – дупеля   – только вариантное окончание Я, вентиль – вентили, табель – табели – только основное окончание И, вексель – вексели и векселя,  китель – кители и кителя – два варианта окончаний.

Comment: @Sibylla, не надо все в одну кучу. Это все отдельной темой - ради бога. Тем более, что там и ответа-то нет содержательного, кроме "смотри в словарь".